# Run multiple queries in SQL PLUS

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am beginner at using SQL and I have searched a lot but couldn't solve that issue. I have about 2500 lines of queries and I need to run all these lines in one shot. When pasting those lines to SQL PLus editor it just executes about 75 lines and ignores the rest of lines
Can you guide me please of how to do that? 
Thanks advanced for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your SQL statement(s) in a script file and execute it

For instance : open notepad. Paste your SQL. Save the file on your desktop and name it **test.sql**

Then in *SQL plus* prompt, just do this :

```
SQL > @C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\test.sql
```

(the `@` is the trick)

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much for great and awesome help